# how to kill a tcp connection in a tcp server program if no FIN/ACK or RST received

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming

I wrote a tcp server program(linux c) and run it on host B

if host A establishes a TCP connection with host B

then A shutdown without sending FIN/ACK

how do I write source codes inside tcp server to kill this tcp connection?

use raw socket to craft s fake RST?

or other ways?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `close()` the server's end of the socket once it has determined that the connection is no longer available.  Eventually, the socket will time out internally and start reporting errors to read/write operations, at which time you can then close it.  If you do not want to wait that long then implement a timeout in your own code, either as a keepalive/ping command in your protocol, or just as a simple timer that keeps track of the last time the client exchanged any data with the server. If the timeout period expires, close the socket regardless of its actual state.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in this case, but if you create a binary file with all the open connections:

```
FILE *ptr_myfile;
ptr_myfile=fopen("test.bin","wb"); //opened sockets
//.. your code ..
sockfd[k] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
fwrite(&sockfd[k], sizeof(sockfd[k]), 1, ptr_myfile_soc);
//.. your code ..
close(ptr_myfile);
```

and if host A shuts down without sending FIN/ACK, in another executable you will read from that file and close the related sockets:

```
fread(&sockfd[k],sizeof(sockfd[k]),1,ptr_myfile_soc);
printf("closing %d \n",k );
close(sockfd[k]);
```

Comment: This seems only a way to keep track of all the open sockets, but I think the OP wanted a way to understand *which* connections have been terminated, and *when*, rather than a way to remember all of them. By the way, why do you want to save them to a file? A file's benefit is its persistence if the program ends unexpectedly. But if that happens, all the connections will be closed by the OS, so I don't see the point of saving them to a file.